Focus on specified element after rerendering
In an Angular app, I've got a view that contains a tabbed interface (NgbNav, from Angular Bootstrap). I'm supposing that this component tracks the choice of tab and uses *ngIf or *ngSwitch or a template conditional to display only the selected tab's content.
The content of each tab begin with an H2 heading of the form
<h2 tabindex="-1" [class.entrypoint]="activeTab === 2">This Tab's Heading</h2>

In the component's SCSS file I have
h2 { border: thick solid orange; }

The component TypeScript includes
activeTab = 1; // what the tab component is bound to
previousTab = 0;

Selecting a tab sets activeTab to the value that corresponds to the tab.
What I want (for accessibility purposes), when a tab is selected, is for the focus to be set to the H2:
if (this.activeTab !== this.previousTab) {
  this.previousTab = this.activeTab;
  Nav.jumpTo('h2.entrypoint');
    // where static method Nav.jumpTo(selector: string) uses
    // document.querySelector to find the HTMLElement
    // and then calls its focus() method and logs the heading's text
}

When I do this in ngAfterViewChecked, I get an error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value for 'attr.tabindex': '-1'. Current value: 'undefined'." I don't even understand this. The string "tabindex" appears nowhere in the TypeScript in my application, so I'm not changing it here. This is being caused by the Nav.jumpTo call.
When I do it in ngAfterViewInit, nothing happens, nothing is logged.
When I do it in ngContentAfterChecked, the result varies. Sometimes I see a border pop briefly around the heading on the new tab and then disappear. Sometimes what's logged is the text of the H2 from the previous tab instead of from the newly selected tab.
I'm trying to figure out a consistent way to catch the change in the active tab and then navigate to that tab's heading after it exists in the document.
I'm starting to think it's a matter of deferring the focus() command by wrapping it in a setTimeout so that it doesn't happen until after rerendering--but for how long? I tried 5 ms and it didn't make any difference. But 1000 ms fixed it. I'd rather have a solid hook than a fuzzy delay.

Setting tabindex="-1" makes it so that the element can not receive focus. Whatever this Nav.jumpTo function is seems to understand this and clears the value in order to set focus on the element. A better solution may be to not set tabindex at all and rather allow *ngIf or *ngSwitch to conditionally render the element as needed. There is no need to set tabindex on an element that is not in the DOM, after all.

That's incorrect.: tabindex="-1" makes it so that an element doesn't receive the focus from tabbing but can receive it directly from scripting.
